# Reading multiple worksheets into data frame(s) in R

Tags: r, excel

I have multiple workbooks with multiple worksheets. In each worksheet, the data starts from a different row number, but can be identified when "ABCD" occurs in the 1st column. I want to apply a function/calculation to each worksheet. However, as the first step, I cannot read in the workbook as a data frame. Tried XLConnect but getting the following error

```
*(Error in ls(envir = envir, all.names = private) : 
  invalid 'envir' argument*
```

My question is how do I read the data from each worksheet into a data frame?

Comment: Show the code that was used.

Comment: Unless you've defined `envir`, the object `envir` doesn't yet exist. Maybe you want something like `ls(envir = .GlobalEnv, ...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XLConnect doesn't work on large EXCEL files. I used RODBC to get it working. See code in the following link if interested. Here's the link:

([Read data from several worksheets from workbook and eliminate comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23413583/read-data-from-several-worksheets-from-workbook-and-eliminate-comments?noredirect=1#comment35887541_23413583)).

Make sure that the R version, Operating system and MS Office versions (64 bit or 32-bit) are identical.

Answer (score 0):

Try the RODBC package `http://cran.r-project.org/package=RODBC`

See also:
`http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-data.html#Reading-Excel-spreadsheets`